# Create multiple tar.gz archives from multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell, sh, tar, gzip

I have a directory full of projects inside, let's say `/Users/Me/Projects`.

Inside of this folder are multiple sub-directories, and even more sub-directories within some of those.

I would like to be able to create a `tar.gz` archive of each archive within `/Users/Me/Projects`, the archives of which would have the same name as the directory.

For example, in the `Projects` folder I'd have, `Project1`, `Project2`, and `Project3`.

What I would like, is to run a script to loop over the directories in `Projects` and not the sub-directories below that to create `Project1.tar.gz`, `Project2.tar.gz`, and `Project3.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `find`:

```
for dir in */; do tar -czvf "${dir%/}".tar.gz "$dir"; done
```

where `*/` makes sure that the glob only matches directories, and `"${dir%/}"` removes the trailing slash from directory names.

If there are hidden directories, they're not matched by `*/`; do get those as well, we can use `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One quick question I had, how can I alter this script to output the newly created archives somewhere besides where they original directories exist? Most of the expanded directories I'm creating these archives from are on my external hard drive and I'd like to place the archives on my internal harddrive. Would it look like `for dir in */; do tar -czvf /Users/Username/Archives/"${dir%/}".tar.gz "$dir"; done` for example?

Comment: @jzg.dev Exactly! If you're unsure about what a command does, you can always just insert an `echo` in front of it and just see the commands that will be executed when you remove it, without actually executing them: `for dir in */; do echo tar ...`

Comment: Thanks for the help! : )

Answer (score 3):

With GNU find:

```
cd /Users/Me/Projects
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar -cvzf {}.tgz {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and a bit trial/error, I came up with this script to programmatically accomplish what I was trying to do.

```
#! /bin/sh

    for dir in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sed 's|./||'`
    do
        tar -czvf /Path/To/Place/Created/Archives/$dir.tar.gz /Path/To/Directories/$dir;
    done
```

Going again off the example I gave in the question, the script would look like this assuming I wanted to create the archives in my `Documents` folder.

```
#! /bin/sh

    for dir in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sed 's|./||'`
    do
        tar -czvf /Users/Me/Documents/$dir.tar.gz /Users/Me/Projects/$dir;
    done
```

**EDIT**

After some further research, it seems that the answer given by Benjamin W. is the most straight forward way to do this. I was hoping to find a way which would strip spaces from the newly created archive names to avoid any possible issues on other file systems, and while the method I described does strip white space, it had a few snags I kept running into.

Comment: Good for you for finding your own answer but [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: you don't have to use `sed` at the end. at if you use `-print0 | xargs -0 tar ...` it will be a very nice answer